# How to get android Mobile UDID from javascript code?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

I need to take udid (android mobile) using **java script** code ?
when user browse the page **java script** take the UDID from mobile device.
if any one know the process please help me.
thank you.

Comment: I need it from java script code ....

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question . I think this is not possible in javascript .
This is only possible in android .
Thanks.